# How to convince a dragon to help people in battle?

Tags: dragons, combat, diplomacy

The first part of stories of Old world ends in a great battle, a battle that will lead to remedy of *Big change* and also (finally) the defeat of the evil king Clerence and the evil faction of Shining ones.

It is clear that the battle cannot be won without the help of dragons. Clerence is powerful even after the suicidal death of his creator. The evil faction of Shining ones is so powerful that even the good faction of Shining ones doesn't have sufficient power to defeat them. Only three very small<sup>*</sup> armies will defend city where the battle with take place.

It is needed to choose someone who would to try to convince the (black) dragons to change their opinion of people and help people in battle - at all costs.

<sup>*</sup> Crimson cavalry - 2500 (cavalry), Dark archers - 5000 (archers), Rainbow knights - 500 (heavy infantry)

---

Water dragons cannot help because they were exterminated and also they could live only in water (the place of the battle is very far from any river). This cannot be changed even by gods.

White dragon Golden glare helped gods and people a few times in history. But she cannot help in the battle because she needs to protect her eggs.

Black dragons live in the depths of Shoreless swamp and hate (at least, they don't trust them very much) people after Clerence almost exterminated them (only few dragons survived).

---

**How to convince (black) dragons to help people in battle?** 
And who should to try to convince them (dragons) to help people in battle?

Comment: Unfortunately you're giving us a lot of information we don't need, while not providing us with the information which might help us answer your question. For example, why are dragons not collaborating with people already? Why are the dragons not helping the Shinning ones instead? Why are dragons not volunteering to help your hero? What exactly makes a dragon "black" other than its colour? Why do we care about water dragons? Just who the heck ***are*** the shinning ones, and why are they so evil? Give us relevant information please.

Comment: Tell us more about your world. Why are the bad guys evil? Why are the good guys worthy of help? Why are the dragons standing by when one of their kind (water dragons) have already been hunted to near extinction? You're asking for help in resolving a diplomatic issue without providing the political information needed to asses the situation.

Comment: Perhaps this could be better in the writers forum - what you need to do is develop motivations, desires and a set of values for the black dragons. The person doing the convincing would find these out and use them to convince the dragons.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: If a medieval city doesn't have bodies of water nearby, it's likely to be small (bad agriculture + only land transportation for the trades). Evacuate it and find some good place with lakes and rivers and water dragons for The Great Battle.

Option 2: Lend some people to babysit Goldenglare's egg while she fights Bad Guys.

Option 3: Wait, so this Clerence guy wiped out almost all black dragons and you can't find a reason for black dragons to fight Clerence? How about "he's gonna finish you all"?